# Hidden Markov model for a time series

Tags: matlab, hidden-markov-models

I want to train a Hidden Markov model for a time series. I tried using Matlab but it is discrete in nature. Can anyone share some good libraries for building continuous HMM on time series. As I am new to HMM, it would be thankful if a code snippet for creating HMM for a time series from the library is shared

Answer (score 0):

There is a Matlab library for continuous HMMs (Gaussian assumption) developed by K. Murphy. Here is the [documentation](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm.html) which includes examples (codes snippets) and [here](https://github.com/probml/pmtk3) is the most recent version of the codes to download.